# iOS, maximum UUID number of beacon ranging in CLLocation

Tags: ios, ibeacon, cllocation

Hi i trying to detect iBeacons.

in case of region monitoring, i knew that maximum UUID number is 20.

How about beacon ranging in CLLocation?
Have maximum UUID number limite?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no hard limit to the number of regions that can be ranged by iOS Core Location.**  I have personally set up 100 regions to range to cover a large number of Proximity UUIDs.

That said, once you get significantly over 100 it starts to have real performance impact on the phone.  There will be one callback to the delegate for each region, so with 100 regions, you will have 100 callbacks per second, and even with minimal processing in the callback CPU starts to spike.    The ultimate limit will be hit when the system simply cannot keep up, and depends on other variables like the number of beacons in the vicinity, the phone model, and other processing going on at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It really helps